# How do I call a method to an object?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

How would I call my method to my other objects?
Been having lots of trouble with everything I've tried.
I'm not that confident with this stuff, just looking on how to tell if the object is safe to drive or not.

```
//Create a constructor function called `Track`. It will accept two parameters - the name of the track and the maximum capacity of the track. 
let track = function(name, capacity){
    this.trackName=name
    this.personnel=0;
    this.cars=[];
    this.cap=capacity;
}


//We'll need a value for the average weight of a person but this value will be the same for all tracks. 
//Add a property `personWeight` on the `Track` prototype so that all instances share the same value. 
track.prototype.personWeight = 200

//Create three methods on the prototype that will calculate track weight, person weight, and if its safe to drive
    function personWeight(){
        personnelWeight = this.personWeight * this.personnel
        return personnelWeight
    }

    function trackWeight(){
        let carsTotal = function myFunc(total, num) {
        return total - num;
    }
        let weightTotal = (this.personnel * this.personWeight) + (this.carsTotal)
        return weightTotal
    }

    function safeToDrive(){
        if(this.trackWeight<this.capacity){
            return true 
        }
    }


//Create two track objects
let trackOne = new track ("Daytona", 25000);
trackOne.cars = [1800, 2400, 2700, 3200, 3600, 3800, 4200]
trackOne.personnel = 10

let trackTwo = new track ("Indiana",15000);
trackTwo.cars = [2000, 2300, 2800, 3000, 3500, 3700, 4000]
trackTwo.personnel = 8


//Call the `safeToDrive` method for truck objects.
```

Comment: Please edit and tag the language in question

Comment: your methods are not part of the object track that you created. your method are currently created outside of the track scope. so you have to call them like `safeToDrive();` The thing is tho. since they are not in the scope of track, `this.personWeight` will likely be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

With the code as it is now, you would use `safeToDrive.call(trackOne)`. However, this is not the straight-forward way you would do it normally.

I guess what you really want is assigning these methods to the prototype:

```js
    track.prototype.safeToDrive = function () {
        if(this.trackWeight<this.capacity){
            return true 
        }
    }
```

Then you'd call them using `trackOne.safeToDrive()`.

The same goes for `personWeight` and `trackWeight`.

---

**A few other observations:**

1. Your check for `this.capacity` won't work because the property is actually called `cap` and not `capacity` according to what you set in your constructor.
2. `safeToDrive` currently returns `true` or nothing, i.e. `undefined`, and not `true` or `false` as you would expect.

   You could fix that by either adding an `else` with `return false` or simply using `return this.trackWeight < this.capacity` instead of the whole `if` condition.
3. Oh, also, your `personnelWeight` variable is accidentally made global. Add a `let` before it. To avoid this in the first place, add `'use strict'` at the top of your file to get warned about this issue next time.
4. I'm not sure what you are doing with `carsTotal` there though, I guess that should be a member function as well (otherwise you couldn't even call it using `this.carsTotal` as you do now). Plus, your indention is wrong there. (Put your file through a [beautifier](https://beautifier.io/) to see what I mean.)
5. Do you mean `truck` instead of `track` maybe...?

Comment: like this?    ```console.log(trackOne.safeToDrive())```  , and the truck weight is supposed to be the sum of the array.